# The background music keep restarting. How to stop it.

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, segue

I create a sharedInstance of a background music and initialize it in the viewDidLoad of the first view controller. But when i change the screen (via segue) and come back to the first screen, the music restart. I believe that's happen because the viewDidLoad it's called again, but i don't want the music to keep restarting every time i comeback to this screen.

How can i manage to the music keep playing without interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the background music in your AppDelegate and not having it tied to any particular view controller.

Although you should typically avoid putting too much code in the AppDelegate, starting/initializing services is a start-up task, and thus makes sense there.

Comment: I should initialize it in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"? I see other solution that involve creating a variable "isMusicPlaying" and a if statement to check every time.

Comment: 1. Yes, if you want the music to start right after launch, put it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. 2. Keeping a variable is also a potential solution, but that means you need to manage it, which can lead to bugs. Are you sure that you're starting the music in `viewDidLoad` and not `viewDidAppear`? `viewDidLoad` should only be called once in the lifetime of a ViewController. You could add the deinit function to your FirstViewController and see if it gets deinitialized for some reason, or put a breakpoint where you start your music, ⌘-Optn tap it, and add a Log Message with `%B - %H`

Comment: Thanks @Alex, i did in the AppleDelegate. But i will try this other solutions above.